# How to return JSON structure in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

i need to return a JSON with this format:

```
{"answers": [{"id": "93", "value":"Ahstron"}, 
             {"id"="94", "value"="Sampers"}]}
```

Im using the return Json() method form ASP MVC Framework, is there a way to specify that this JSOn is a collection of **answers** like in the sample code? or must i create my own?

with the

```
return Json(answers);
```

i just get this:

```
[{"id": "93", "value":"Ahstron"}, 
{"id"="94", "value"="Sampers"}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
return Json(new {answers = answers});
```

Answer (score 2):

It almost worked, 
the correct syntax is:

```
return Json(new { answers = answers});
```

Thx a lot =)